# damaged PDF data from database

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server-2008, devexpress, xaf

I'm using MS SQL 2008 i have a table with varbinary(max) type column
This table has many uploaded pdf files (byte arrays)
I'm converting this bytes to pdf files 
by this code:

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream
                (@"D:\EIFiles\test.pdf", FileMode.Create))
        {
            fs.Write(byte, 0, byte.Length);
        }
```

Many of the pdf files can be opened, but some of them can not be open because adobe reader alerts "damaged file" message.
Note: All of  them can be open via program (written in Devexpress XAF) which uses this DB

Comment: When you say "can be open via program".  Does that program display the PDF?

Comment: Try to use several alternative PDF-readers for damaged files and you'll know if the problem is in reader or in file.

Comment: Feel free to send me a sample PDF and I can examine it for you with a full version of Adobe Acrobat. Also check collation on your sql server  i have had similar issues when using unicode to.

Comment: I think, this is the fs.Write problem, readers are works completely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DevExpress XAF implementation of the default `FileData` type compresses the stream (Gzip) before saving it. You will not be able to read the contents without decompressing the stream first. You can use `CompressionUtils.Decompress()` which is in the DevExpress.Persistent.Base assembly.

Alternatively you could implement your own version of `FileData` and change this behaviour. Look at the source (or use a decompiler) and remove the `[ValueConverter(typeof(CompressionConverter))]` attribute from the `Content` property.